# voice encryption on fly in mobile phones

Tags: voip

I want to encrypt voice calls on the fly. so which programming language should be preferred for symbian os. Are any API available for this purpose. which channel could be preferably used?

Comment: you should probably learn programming before writing anything that needs security

Comment: @Lie: A bit harsh, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_do_I_start_programming_for_Symbian_OS%3F about the different possibilities (programming language wise).

BTW: A good programmer can write faster code in Visual Basic than a bad programmer in Assembler.