# voice encryption

Tags: encryption, symbian

I want to develop an application to encrypt voice calls on the fly. Is it feasible?
which programming language should be preferred for symbian O.S

Comment: Exact duplicate (same user): [voice encryption on fly in mobile phones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007651/voice-encryption-on-fly-in-mobile-phones)

Comment: Hi, on Symbian the only possibility is C++ for such application. BR STeN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has already been done: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype_security

To implement it, you would need a fast language (a delay of no more than maybe 10 milliseconds, because you still have network latency to deal with) so something like C or C++, maybe Java when used with JIT. Check out [Java SE Security Package](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2001/05/03/java_security.html) for simple SSL connections.

Of course, the easy way to do this would just be an ssh or VPN tunnel.

Comment: Thank You sir but i wanted to implement this application for mobiles and is in search of some API to access voice calls so that they can be encrypted and could be sent through VOIP. can you please suggest some API for j2me or symbian c++ which would help me in my job.

Comment: Does skype run on Symbian OS? I don't think so.